# Segue to another view controller with label connected crashes

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, crash, storyboard

I am using a storyboard to connect two different view controllers. When I click on the cell I want it to segue into another view controller (what it usually does). But anytime I link a link a label with an outlet and try to segue, it crashes.

These are some images you may need: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aym2V.jpg.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to seague with a label? can you explain

Comment: @LithuT.V When I link a label in the view controller that I am segueing to, it crashes. But if I delete the connection, it works perfectly.

Comment: what is the link u are talking about?

Comment: An outlet.I link the outlet with the label. I run my app. Everything works well until I click on the cell which is supposed to segue to another view controller. It crashes. When I unlink the label, the app is completely functional and segues to the view controller without any problems.

Comment: just adding the outlet.not doing something on the label after that?

Comment: Nothing on the label. Just connecting with an outlet. See the pictures for more details.

Comment: remove that custom class name in ib and try again

Comment: Is terminalsviewcontroller the view controller you are segueing to?

Comment: @orange9792 Yes. That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Click on your terminalsviewcontroller file owner in storyboard and select the connections inspector. Check for a connection called key test that has an exclamation point next to it and delete it.

Comment: Casey is right, this usually happens when your nib/storyboard archive is extracted and you have an outlet in your nib/storyboard which isn't properly hooked up to code.  You should ensure the connection is not screwed up.